# Laravel 5.2: Auth::check() keeps returning false

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5, uuid

I'm starting out a new Laravel 5.2 project, and I've run into a strange authentication problem: `Auth::check()` returns false constantly.

If you think this is a duplicate, read on. I've tried multiple suggestions to fixing this issue with no luck.

The setting:

- The application environment is Laravel Homestead's `php-7` branch (Vagrant box).
- User models use UUIDs instead if IDs (table has auto-incrementing `id` switched to a 36-character `uuid` primary key column).
- User model `primaryKey` has been changed from `id` to `uuid` and `incrementing` has been set to false.
- Used `artisan make:auth` to generate authentication baseline to work with.
- Authentication routes have been set for `getLogin`, `postLogin`, `getEmail`, `postEmail`, `getReset` and `postReset` and they are working fine.
- `web` middleware is used for all routes in the application at the moment.
- Auth config and session config inside `config` dir are at defaults (except a namespace change for auth model).
- Passing in invalid credentials triggers validation errors properly.
- After logging in the `redirectPath` on `AuthController` does work, but the `guest` middleware hijacks the request and redirects user back to login route.

I can create users fine and change their forgotten passwords using the created route definitions. I can "log in" on the login route, but `Auth::check()` always returns false in the `guest` middleware (`Middleware\Authenticate` class).

I've tried the following session drivers without success:

- File
- Redis
- Cookie
- Database

I even tried to revert the `users` table primary key to named `id`, but that didn't change anything.

Something I noticed: as my user IDs are actually char(36) UUIDs, the database session driver did not save the `user_id` properly: it saved the *integer* characters from the user UUID and then cut off the rest of the value (e.g. `users.uuid` `3f2358907afafaf` becomes `session.user_id` `3`), or `0` if the user ID starts with a non-numeric character (`a-f`).

I've found a huge amount of questions and threads and search results for this same issue. I tried the things most said would work, but I didn't get it working still:

- I have set the `$user->primaryKey` protected property to `uuid` (which affects `$model->getKey()` and `$model->getAuthIdentifier()` too).
- I have tried multiple different session drivers with no success.
- I have tried reverting to the `users.id` column name instead of `users.uuid`, no change.
- I have cleared all caches I can think of.
- I have checked that there is no whitespace output before views output (need to dig a bit deeper though in case I missed some files).

The only thing which I have not properly tried yet is to just switch back the auto-incrementing IDs for users (instead of UUIDs). I've tied the UUID concept pretty tight already but I'll see what I can do to solve this issue.

Please do ask for details if I'm missing something in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think laravel has a bug. It often keeps returning `false` on each `Auth::check()` after the execution of `Auth::attempt()`

Try editing the `$middleware[];` in Kernel.php to:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: This one helps too, if `Auth::check()` fails on error pages.

Comment: This seems to provoke another issue: on authentication errors during login, the error messages do not show up anymore, if I add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to the global middleware. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Okay. The last mentioned issue raised up because of misconfiguration of my Http/Kernel.php. I had to remove `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` from my `$middlewareGroups` array to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's Eloquent Model assume that each table has a primary key column named **id**.

So if you have changed the primary key of your Users table to something else, your Auth session wont be set.

You should define a **$primaryKey** property to override this convention just like defining $table in the Model class like:

```
protected $primaryKey = "your_field_ID";
```

May be late, but should help others who come here looking for answers.